# Defining module variables from functions

Tags: function, variables, python-3.x, scope, flake8

I've been finally getting into Python, and have noticed something strange, that **works in Java**, but **not in Python**.

When I type the following:

```
fn = ""  # Local filename storage.

def read(filename):
    fn = filename
    return open(filename, 'r').read()
```

My flake8 linter for Atom gives me the following error:

> F841 - local variable 'fn' is assigned to but never used.

I'm assuming this means that the variable is being defined on the **def** level, and not the **module** level, which I intend on doing. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

I've searched Google, with multiple wordings, but can't seem to word it in a way that the correct results display...
**Any ideas on how I can be able to achieve module-level variable definitions from the function-level?**

Comment: `fn` is assigned, but instead of `fn`, the code is using `filename`. Why don't you use `fn`?  `return open(fn, 'r').read()`

Comment: @falsetru I'm accessing the file-level `fn` from another class. Its storage for later usage.

Comment: Then, you need to declare it as a global `global fn`

Comment: @falsetru Then how do I define it from function-scope? ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a module level variable from the function by doing:

```
import sys

def read(filename):        
    module = sys.modules[__name__]
    setattr(module, 'fn', filename)
    return open(filename, 'r').read()
```

However, it's a very strange necessity. Consider to change your architecture.

**UPD:** Let's consider an example:

```
# module1
# uncomment it to fix NameError and AttributeError
# some_var = '' 

def foo(val):
    global some_var
    some_var = val


# module2
from module1 import *
print(some_var)  # raises NameError: name 'some_var' is not defined

foo('bar')
print(some_var)  # still raises NameError: name 'some_var' is not defined


# module3
import module1
print(module1.some_var)  # raises AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'some_var'

foo('bar')
print(module1.some_var)  # prints 'bar' even without some_var = '' definition in the module1
```

So, it's not so obvious how `global` behaves during the import process. I think, that manually doing `setattr(module, 'attr_name', value)` during the `read()` call is more clear.

Comment: What is the key difference between your answer and the other in functionality and the underlying workings?

Comment: With such approach you can set a variable during the execution of the `read` function not only to the module where it was defined. Meanwhile, any code execution during `import` leads to very badly testable architectures. Try to avoid it. Often during the testing process you can't omit importing, however, you need that some code will be mocked/stubbed.

Comment: And the difference between that and global definitions?

Comment: @frayment, actually using `global fn` and manually setting `fn` attribute to the `read`'s module behave the same way.

Comment: Hmm... Hard to come to a decision, but I'm giving you the upvote, even though I prodded you with my difference question. For now I think I'll stick with globals, but it's great to see both sides explained well. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to declare `fn` as a global variable (module-level), use [`global` statement](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-global-statement).

```
def read(filename):
    global fn  # <-----
    fn = filename
    return open(filename, 'r').read()
```

BTW, `;` is optional. Don't use it.

Comment: Alright then. I'll try this. BTW, does globalising it from the variable-level import it automatically when `from io import *` is called?

Comment: @frayment, Yes it does unless you define `__all__` to manually control it. See https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package

Comment: To have an access to the `fn` from the other module after importing you have to not only define it as a `global` within the `read()` function, but also define it on the module level (for example as `fn = ''`). Without such definition you won't get an access to the `fn` after doing `from io import *` and before calling `read()`.